# Wrapping label in the scale_fill_discrete() function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to wrap the labels that I specified in the `scale_fill_discrete()' function in the following codes:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x= What_is_NMD,  group=Gender, fill = str_wrap(What_is_NMD))) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., fill = factor(..x..)), stat="count") +
  geom_text(aes( label = scales::percent(..prop.., accuracy = 0.01),
             y= ..prop.. ), stat= "count", vjust = -.5) +
 labs(x="What is NMD?", y = "Percent", fill="What is NMD?") +
 facet_grid(~Gender) +
 scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
 theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),legend.key.height=unit(1.2, "cm"))+
 scale_fill_discrete(labels=c("Is an inherited disorder, having genetic basis","Due to 
                               dietary deficiency", "Term is known but don’t know the 
                                  etiology", "Completely unknown"))
```

The codes produce the following figure

[image]

How can I wrap the label?

Comment: `str_wrap` should be in the labels. Try `scale_fill_discrete(labels = str_wrap(c("your labels), width = 10))`

Comment: benson23's comment also works for labels in the leggend